# Does homotopy type theory teach us anything about imprecise models of the real world?

Tags: mathematical-modeling, deformation-theory, homotopy-type-theory

Models of the real world are necessarily imprecise. Let’s say

- the real world looks like $A$
- the model’s assumptions are $A'$
- the model derives that $A' \to B'$

Does adding deformations $A' \overset{\rm{deform}}{\rightsquigarrow} A$ to the usual logic allow us to infer anything about $B$ in $B \overset{?}{\leftarrow} B' \overset{\rm{existing\ model}}{\leftarrow} A' \overset{\rm{deform}}{\leftarrow} A$?

Comment: I'm not sure of deformation of models generally, but this made me think of homotopic continuation methods for numerical analysis.